# (DISCORD.PY) Any way to detect a user's discord game when they have a custom status?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm planning to create a code wherein if somebody is playing a certain game, they will get kicked and a message will appear. The code works if a member doesn't have a custom status but if they do, nothing happens because it detects their custom status as their activity. I tried using discord.Game but I can't seem to make it detect the game if a user has a custom status. Any help is appreciated!

```
@client.event
async def on_presence_update(member, after):
    games = ['List', 'Of', 'Games']
    if after.activity.name in games:
        channel = client.get_channel(*insert channel id*)
        await member.kick(reason=None)
        await channel.send(f"{member.mention} has been kicked for playing {after.activity.name}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop through all your activities in `after` presence and check if games matching you list. There is attribute named **activities** in `Presence` object where it will list all the activities that user currently doing even including games and their custom statuses.

```
@client.event
async def on_presence_update(member, before, after):
    games = ['List', 'Of', 'Games']
    for activity in after.activities:
        if activity.name in games:
            channel = client.get_channel(*insert channel id*)
            await member.kick(reason=None)
            await channel.send(f"{member.mention} has been kicked for playing {activity.name}")
```